# Rails unit test fixtures using environment variables throw MySQL error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, testing

Take for example the following test fixture:

```
fixture_1:
  name: MyString
  username: <%= Rails.configuration.database_configuration['test']['username'] %>
```

Throws the following error when executing the tests:

```
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'adapter' in 'field list':
```

However, I can load fixtures into the DB manually with no problems.

Using Rails 3.2.11 and Ruby 1.9.2.

Rails bug or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try running `rake db:test:prepare` before executing the tests - it seems you have added that field later to the development db, but not yet to the test db.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Tried running 'db:test:prepare' to no avail.